# Yield both items and callback request in scrapy

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to both Python and Scrapy.

I'm trying to get my spider to gather urls from the start url, follow those gathered urls and both:

1. scrape the next page for specific items (and eventually return them)
2. gather more specific urls from the next page and follow these urls.

I want to be able to continue this process of yielding both items and callback requests, but I am not quite sure how to do it.
Currently my code only returns urls, and no items. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
class VSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vs5"
    allowed_domains = ["votesmart.org"]
    start_urls = [
                  "https://votesmart.org/officials/WA/L/washington-state-legislative#.V8M4p5MrKRv",
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        #this gathers links to the individual legislator pages, it works
        for href in response.xpath('//h5/a/@href'): 
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        #these xpaths are on the next page that the spider should follow, when it first visits an individual legislator page
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/section/div/div/div'):
            item = LegislatorsItems()
            item['current_office'] = sel.xpath('//tr[1]/td/text()').extract()
            item['running_for'] = sel.xpath('//tr[2]/td/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        #this is the xpath to the biography of the legislator, which it should follow and scrape next
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="folder-bio"]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse2, meta={'items': items})

    def parse2(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = response.meta['items']
        #this is an xpath on the biography page
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/'):
            item = LegislatorsItems()
            item['tester'] = sel.xpath('//div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]').extract()
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

Thanks!

Comment: After a quick glance at your code, I guess `return items` in the last line shall have had a different indent level.

Comment: Other than what starrify mentioned, Is `parse2` even reachable? Could you maybe post crawl log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 levels of your problem.

**1.** Bio url is not available with JS disabled. Turn off JS in your browser and check this page:
https://votesmart.org/candidate/126288/derek-stanford

You should see the tag with empty href and correct url hidden under comment.

```
<a href="#" class="folder" id="folder-bio">
<!--<a href='/candidate/biography/126288/derek-stanford' itemprop="url" class='more'>
           See Full Biographical and Contact Information</a>-->
```

For extracting bio url, you can get this comment with xpath selector "/comment()", and then extract url with regexp.

Or, if url structure is common for all pages, just form url yourself: replace "/candidate/" in link with "/candidate/biography/".

> **NB!** If you face unexpected issues, one of the first actions - disable JS and look at the page as Scrapy see it. Test all selectors.

---

**2.** Your usage of items is very complicated. If "one item = one person", you should just define one item in "parse_person" and pass it to "parse_bio".

Take a look at the updated code. I rewrote some parts while finding the issue. Notes:

- You don't need (in most cases) to create "items" list and append items to it. Scrapy manage with items itself.
- "sel = Selector(response)" has no sense in your code, you can throw it.

This code is tested with Scrapy 1.0 and Python 3.5, though with earlier versions should work too.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class VSSpider(Spider):
    name = "vs5"
    allowed_domains = ["votesmart.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://votesmart.org/officials/WA/L/washington-state-legislative"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('h5 a::attr(href)').extract():
            person_url = response.urljoin(href)
            yield Request(person_url, callback=self.parse_person)

    def parse_person(self, response):  # former "parse1"
        # define item, one for both parse_person and bio function
        item = LegislatorsItems()

        # extract text from left menu table and populate to item
        desc_rows = response.css('.span-abbreviated td::text').extract()
        if desc_rows:
            item['current_office'] = desc_rows[0]
            item['running_for'] = desc_rows[1] if len(desc_rows) > 1 else None

        # create right bio url and pass item to it
        bio_url = response.url.replace('votesmart.org/candidate/', 
                                       'votesmart.org/candidate/biography/')
        return Request(bio_url, callback=self.parse_bio, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_bio(self, response):  # former "parse2"
        # get item from meta, add "tester" data and return
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['tester'] = response.css('.item.first').xpath('//li[3]').extract()
        print(item)   # for python 2: print item 
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about JS, that makes things a lot easier. Everything in your code works fine for me, except for `parse_bio`. It returns the correct urls (of the bios), but also just {'tester': []}, instead of the specified xpaths, which makes me think it's a simple problem with the xpath selector, but when I check it in Google Chrome's console, it works. Also, is there a specific reason why you changed it to css? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind! My xpath selectors were definitely wrong.